# Triying to set a default value in react-select but is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-select

I'm using [react-select](https://react-select.com/). Additionally, I'm fetching some accounts. I'm trying to set the current license of the user to the default value when the modal opens. I'm getting the value right but I don't know why when my modal opens, it's not selecting the actual value. I'm using the `defaultValue` prop, so it just assigns the license and lets me change option afterwards. If I use value prop, then it will select the right option but I'm unable to change options.

Here is the code:

```
function EditModal({ isOpen, onClose, account, licenses }: Props) {
  const selectOptions = useMemo(() => {
    const licensesFormatted =
      licenses?.map((license) => ({
        value: license.id,
        label: license.accountName,
      })) || [];

    // Add a none option
    licensesFormatted.unshift({ value: '', label: 'None' });

    // If the account has a license, add it to the top of the list
    account?.License &&
      licensesFormatted.unshift({
        value: account?.License?.id,
        label: `Current - ${account?.License?.accountName}`,
      });

    return licensesFormatted;
  }, [account, licenses]);

  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={isOpen}
      title='Edit account'
      onClose={() => {
        onClose();
      }}>
      <LicenseSelect
        options={selectOptions}
        defaultValue={selectOptions[0]} //Here I'm setting the first item in the array to be the default, it can be or the current license, or none option 
        onChange={(value) => {
          // setValue('licenseId', value);
          console.log('Set Value', value);
        }}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

My end goal is, when the user tries to edit their account, their actual license should be selected automatically so that they don't edit it by accident.

I tried setting a useState to store first option, and then update it with the `onChange` prop, but since the `useState` value is not up to date when it gets called by its Set function, I'm getting outdated value when `onChange` is triggered.